# How to overlay WMS (Web Map Service) on GeoServer to Openlayers Map

Tags: openlayers, geoserver, wms

I am trying to overlay WMS (Web Map Service) in localhost GeoServer over Openlayers Map. However, the WMS layers won't display. How to fix this?

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.9.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.9.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <title>OpenLayers example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Web Map Service with Openlayers Overlay</h2>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <p> WMS Layers
    <input type="checkbox" id="befalk">befalk
    <input type="checkbox" id="bbgg_Lund2">bbgg_Lund2
    <input type="checkbox" id="vag_alla_ny">vag_alla_ny
</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var wms_layer=[]
      if(document.getElementById('befalk').checked){
        wms_layer.push('befalk');
        console.log('befalk checked!');
      }
      
      if(document.getElementById('bbgg_Lund2').checked){
        wms_layer.push('bbgg_Lund2');
        console.log('bbgg_Lund2 checked!');
      }
      
      if(document.getElementById('vag_alla_ny').checked){
        wms_layer.push('vag_alla_ny');
        console.log('vag_alla_ny checked!');
      }
      
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          }),
          new ol.layer.Tile({
    extent: [13.1354,55.6798,13.2583,55.7433],
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
      url: 'https://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',
      params: {'LAYERS': 'wsLundRoads:befalk', 'TILED': true},
      serverType: 'geoserver',
      // Countries have transparency, so do not fade tiles:
      transition: 0,
    }),
  }),
        ],

        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([13.191007, 55.704660]),
          zoom: 15
        })
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to listen for click events on the checkbox, rebuild the array for the layers parameter, then call `updateParams`.  This example combines two of the sample layers used in OpenLayers examples

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>WMS GetFeatureInfo (Tile Layer)</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.9.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      html, body, .map {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
      #map {
        position: relative;
      }
      #form {
        z-index: 1;
        opacity: 1;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.9.0/build/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <form id="form">
      <input type="checkbox" id="ne:ne" checked>ne:ne
      <input type="checkbox" id="topp:states">topp:states
    </form>
    <script>
      var wms_layers = [];
      var wmsSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wms',
        params: {'LAYERS': '', 'TILED': true},
        serverType: 'geoserver',
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
      });

      var wmsLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: wmsSource
      });

      var neCheckbox = document.getElementById('ne:ne');
      neCheckbox.addEventListener('click', checkboxChanged);
      var statesCheckbox = document.getElementById('topp:states');
      statesCheckbox.addEventListener('click', checkboxChanged);
      function checkboxChanged(){
        wms_layers = [];
        if (neCheckbox.checked) {
          wms_layers.push('ne:ne');
        }
        if (statesCheckbox.checked) {
          wms_layers.push('topp:states');
        }
        wmsSource.updateParams({'LAYERS': wms_layers});
        wmsLayer.setVisible(wms_layers.length > 0);
      }
      checkboxChanged();

      var view = new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 1
      });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          }),
          wmsLayer
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: view
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Error: Access image from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.